# Const pointer conversions

Tags: c++

Can someone explain whats going on here? What kind of mathematical logic is being used in here?

> (4.4/4) A conversion can add cv-qualifiers at levels other than the
>   first in multi-level pointers, subject to the following rules:51) Two
>   pointer types T1 and T2 are similar if there exists a type T and
>   integer n > 0 such that: T 1 is cv 1 , 0 pointer to cv 1 , 1 pointer
>   to . . . cv 1 ,n − 1 pointer to cv 1 ,n T and T 2 is cv 2 , 0 pointer
>   to cv 2 , 1 pointer to . . . cv 2 ,n − 1 pointer to cv 2 ,n T where
>   each cv i, j is const, volatile, const volatile, or nothing.  The
>   n-tuple of cv-qualifiers after the first in a pointer type, e.g., cv 1
>   , 1 , cv 1 , 2 , . . . , cv 1 ,n in the pointer type T1, is called the
>   cv-qualification signature of the pointer type.  An expression of type
>   T 1 can be converted to type T 2 if and only if the following
>   conditions are satisfied: —  the pointer types are similar. — for
>   every j > 0, if const is in cv 1 , j then const is in cv 2 , j , and
>   similarly for volatile. — if the cv 1 , j and cv 2 , j are different,
>   then const is in every cv 2 ,k for 0 < k < j.

Comment: Illustration for your question in this (more concrete) question:
[Why is the conversion from char*** to char*const** invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200807/why-is-the-conversion-from-char-to-charconst-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really call it mathematical logic. This is (IMO) a pretty good example of type theory and type inferencing. For a general overview, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) is your friend.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.