# Why is the conversion from char*** to char*const** invalid?

Tags: c++

According to [*N4606*](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf), 4.5 [conv.qual] paragraph 3 reads

> A prvalue expression of type `T1` can be converted to type `T2` if the following conditions are satisfied, where cv<sub>i</sub><sup>j</sup> denotes the cv-qualifiers in the cv-qualification signature of T<sub>j</sub>:
>
> - ...
> - **If the cv<sup>1</sup><sub>i</sub> and cv<sup>2</sup><sub>i</sub> are different, then const is in every cv<sup>2</sup><sub>k</sub> for 0 < k < i.**

The final bullet above suggests that the following conversion fails.

```
T1 : pointer to / pointer to /       pointer to / T
T2 : pointer to / pointer to / const pointer to / T
```

In order to succeed, `T2` must be `pointer to / const pointer to / const pointer to / T`. **Isn't `T2` sufficient just for being more cv-qualified than `T1`?** Why are more cv-qualifiers in lower dimensions necessary for the conversion to succeed?

Comment: My feeling is that you are seeking to discuss and understand better the question you asked. I have to admit that I wonder why the tag *language-lawyer* exists. In my opinion that is not really an SO question. Maybe try other StackExchange forums? Programming for example? ....

Comment: @Elyasin You're right. I came here to seek for a good explanation. If no answers show up, I'll consider looking for other forums. For *language-lawyer* tag, I added it because this question is related to the standard. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Note that this has been the rule since time immemorial.

Comment: The question makes it (incorrectly) sound as if this was a change in the next version of the standard. I'm not sure if this was really your intention; perhaps you should reword it as a service for future readers.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I agree. My intent (for mentioning the draft) was just to clearly express the source. Also, I added *c++11* tag in order to draw more attention. I'll edit it.

Comment: Isn't there an explanation and demonstration in the very same standard section?

Comment: @Elyasin: It looks like you have mistaken Stack Overflow for a code debugging/writing service. It is not. This is a great question (or, it would be had it not been answered a gazillion times before), far better than the constant stream of localised poop that forms the bulk of the site's input nowadays. Furthermore, no Stack Exchange site is a "forum".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right... I have mistaken the example was for another bullet. In fact, the answer accepted below seemed to be just edited version of the example in the standard. Forgive me...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't understand your accusation. Why so aggressive? Try to relax. I simply stated what I think. Maybe for you it is a great question, but that is not a requirement. "forum", "q&a site", "q&a forum", "network" or whatever, no need to ride on terminology really...

Comment: @Elyasin There is nothing aggressive about Lightness' comment-- they did no more than stating their disagreement. That is not to spite you. It is important to publicly disagree about this sort of issue, as it is not just a matter of personal opinion. For instance, every time someone shares an opinion about what they think is on-topic or off-topic in Stack Overflow, they nudge the whole community a tiny little bit in the direction of that opinion. If you care about the site and disagree, stating your disagreement publicly is an entirely natural way of countering that nudge.

Comment: That's fair enough. The first sentence in lightning's comment made me frown a bit... was not necessary I think.

Comment: @duplode: Exactly!

Comment: There [should be a note that explains why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29240053/1708801) ... that question is also quite similar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
char str[] = "p1 should always point here.";
char* const p1 = str;
char** p2 = nullptr;
char*** p3 = &p2;

char str2[] = "Can we make p1 point to here?"
// p1 = str2; // does not work: const violation

// But:
char*const** p4=p3; // if it were allowed
*p4 = &p1; // no const violation, as *p4 is of type char*const*
**p3 = str2; // oops, changed p1!
```

So if the conversion in question were allowed,  you'd get to change a constant variable (p1) without any formal const violation.

Comment: Can you explain when `T2` is `char*volatile**`? I don't think the same principle applies.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: The same principle applies for volatile, except that the effect is different: Instead of changing something that should not be changed, you risk that a change is not properly committed to memory.

Comment: @celtschk It all makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @Il-seobBae General rule of thumb is that the same syntax and semantics apply to all cv-qualified versions of a type (i.e. non-qualified `T`, `const T`, `volatile T`, and `const volatile T`), with the difference being in what effect it has.  Case in point, `const` correctness rules can be applied to `volatile` correctness as well, by simply changing every `const` to `volatile`.

Comment: Note the [standard has a similar example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29240053/1708801) in the same section.